# Retrieving object from array based on ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array (myElems) with objects (list items).
I'd like to fish out from this array an element with `ID` matching 'foo'.
'foo' string is currently stored in a var 'targetItem'
Last, I need to grab that matching element's position.top

```
var targetItem = 'foo'; // value of this var is set dynamically
$(myElems).grep(function(ele){
retun ele.id == menuItem;
});
var loc = // [returned from array].position.top;
```

...yes, I know this is hodgepodge... I don't know how to syntax this

Thanks

EDIT:
creation of myElems

```
var myElems = [];

    $('#menu').children('li').each(function() {
        myElems.push( $(this) ); 
    });
```

html:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="foo">FOO ITEM</li>
    <li id="boo">BOO ITEM</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is your myElems array of DOM references? Also clarify what you mean by position.top. Do you mean the CSS _top_ attribute? Or do you mean the index of the found element within the array collection?

Answer (score 1):

**JS**

```
var ele = $('#foo').attr('id')
var myElems = [];

$('#menu').children('li').each(function() {
    myElems.push( $(this).attr('id') ); 
});

var targetItem = 'foo'; // value of this var is set dynamically
var newelement =  $.grep(myElems, function( ele, i ){
                      return ele == targetItem ;
                     //console.log("This is the position of matched item - ", + i);
                   });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xt6Wh/2/

Check if `ele.id` is getting the required value. In the fiddle I am taking the value from a `div` - just to show that the logic works. I am not sure where you are getting the `ele.id` from. Hence I took the assumption.

Comment: how do I use the returned value? close it in a var for instance to use elsewhere?

Comment: for some reason it would throw error on `$(myElem).grep...` so I had to use `$.grep(myElem, function...` (object has no method grep). Still, `newelement` returns `[]`, empty array?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake...that's the correct format...Are you getting the value of `ele.id` correct ?

Comment: my array hold objects (list elements, not strings as your example), would that be of importance?

Comment: Can you post the array ?

Comment: I edited post, the `ele.id` came from a source I was using trying to get this ting working... it actually has not context in my example afaik, sorry for confusion

Comment: ok then, you need to use `ele` instead of `ele.id`. Check edited answer

Comment: could you clarify what `ele` an `i` arguments represent?

Comment: `ele` represents each element in array, and `i` represents it's index(position at which it is present in array)

Comment: ...my brain is fried from looking at this all day. I need to take a breather. Thank you for all your help Ani

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can think of off hand is to just iterate over the array and go from there using grep

```
$.grep(myElems,function(value,id){
    return id == targetItem;
});
```

Let me know if that works for you, else I'll edit my answer based on your comments. This is the best I can give you given your code.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla js.

```
el = myElems.filter(function (elem) {
    return elem["id"] == "foo";
})
```

This will get you an array of elements matching "foo". Then you can check if you have something there:

```
if(el.length > 0) el = el[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// To get the correct element you can just stick to CSS id selector:
var target = $('#menu').children('li#' + targetItem);
// to get the CSS top value you can do
var top = target.css("top");
```

Of course, you can check for the *target.length* if there is a case where no target element is present.

http://jsfiddle.net/jeVSJ/

Comment: I have to reach out to the array as that is what is created dynamically and holds the position value at the time the given item is pushed to the array

Comment: @user3024007 according to your generation code of the myElems, this will produce the same result. Your CSS top attribute value is referenced through the DOM reference regardless how you obtain it. Perhaps you can elaborate.